# how to count quantity of different between 2 tables?

Tags: sql-server, count, case, difference

i need to count different between 2 tables (same table from 2 different days) to see what have changed.

for example table 1:

[image]

table 2:

[image]

and i want to get this table:

[image]

i try this code:

```
select a.of_key , case when a.color != b.color then count (a.color) ELSE 0 END AS color,  
        case when a.side != b.side then count (a.side) else 0 end as side   
from 130720 A right JOIN 100720 B
ON a.of_key = b.of_key and a.num = b.bum
group by a.of_key
```

it is not working

please help

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your aggregate outside the case statement:

```
select a.of_key , SUM(case when a.color != b.color then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS color,  
        SUM(case when a.side != b.side then 1 else 0 end) as side   
from 130720 A right JOIN 100720 B
ON a.of_key = b.of_key and a.num = b.bum
group by a.of_key
```